# Are most Python HTTP API packages incompatible with asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am looking at asyncio tutorials for Python, and I noticed that they say you need to use `aiohttp` module for compatibility with `asyncio`. That's fine if you're writing low-level calls, but if I'm using an API wrapper (like `praw` for reddit), there's no guarantee that they use `aiohttp`  under the hood.

Are API wrappers like `praw` generally not compatible with `asyncio`? Is there any way to use the two together?

Comment: I guess you're right saying that most API wrapper libraries (except the ones saying it explicitely of course) aren't using `aiohttp` under the hood. However, depending on what you are trying to achieve, you can surely use libraries making blocking requests within a workflow using asyncio; for example by running these blocking requests in a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-concurrent.futures) without blocking the [event-loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html) while waiting for the request to be completed.

Comment: Thanks, yes ThreadPoolExecutor looks like what I actually want